# (JQuery) For Loop not Incrementing

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, for-loop

I'm pretty new to JQuery, but this is an annoyingly simple problem that's really getting to me.

I'm trying to fade in/fade out/increment/repeat through an array of strings in JavaScript, but the for loop is always exactly 4

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var words=["Fantastic","Exiting", "Professional", "Life Changing", "Exactly What You Are Looking For..."];
    for(var j = 0; j < words.length; j++){
        $('#word').html(words[j]).fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn().delay(1000);
    }
});
```

I'm sure its just a stupid mistake that I'm blind to because its my code, but as I'm on my own at the moment can someone call it out for me?

Cheers in advance guys.

Comment: "The for loop is always exactly 4"... What do you mean ?

Comment: Because the for loop does not wait until the code inside is done running. So you will see the last item because that was the last thing to run!

Comment: Write a function taking `j` as input that does the `.html...` bit onwards - and uses the callback from the last delay to increment `j` and call the function again.

Comment: the for loop did its job before html finish its work

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/R5qsH/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is (probably) that `fadeOut` and `fadeIn` are executed in *async*, so that what actually happens is something like this:

1. Your loop is started, `j == 0`.
2. jQuery fetches the `#word` element, and sets its contents to `word[0]`
3. jQuery queues four animations on the element: `fadeOut`, `delay`, `fadeIn` and `delay` again.
4. `fadeOut` starts running
5. The loop continues, since the animation runs async - `j == 1`
6. The same thing happens here - jQuery finds the `#word` element and sets its contents to `word[1]`, and queues the same four animations again.
7. `fadeOut` is still not done. And if it is, `delay(1000)` is definitely not.
8. The next three loop runs run just as above, ending up setting the contents to `word[4]` before even the first `fadeOut` has finished.
9. The animation events run, all in their turn, showing the contents as `word[4]` every time the element fades in.

You need to use callback functions to postpone updating the contents of the element until the animation events are finished.

Comment: As soon as you said async I knew it. In 6 mins you will have a nice green tick to add to your collection. Cheers mate

Answer (score 0):

If I understand right, you're always seeing the final string fade in/out.

That's because the loop doesn't delay the next iteration with the fade effects.

You'll need to change your logic so either the value does not increment until after fade effects, or move away from using an explicit loop.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var words=["Fantastic","Exiting", "Professional", "Life Changing", "Exactly What You Are Looking For..."];
    //run against first string in array
    $('#word').html(words[0]).fadeOut(complete).delay(1000).fadeIn().delay(1000);

    //callback function
    function complete() {
        //check which word we're currently on
        var index = words.indexOf($(this).html());

        //if it's not the last word, run the code with the next
        if (index < words.length) {
            $(this).html(words[index+1]).fadeOut(complete).delay(1000).fadeIn().delay(1000);
        }
     }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/S9MQ9/1/

Answer (score 0):

This might solve your problem, give it a try and tell us if it worked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var words=["Fantastic","Exiting", "Professional", "Life Changing", "Exactly What You Are Looking For..."];
  for(var j = 0; j < words.length; j++){
    (function (index) {
      $('#word').html(words[index]).fadeOut().delay(1000).fadeIn().delay(1000);
    }(j));
  }
});
```